# R: for loop while subsetting a dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, knn

I am performing text classification, I have created features and I have multiple labels to train and predict which are basically the binary variables, which I want to predict.

Here is my code, and log of the error.

```
for (col in colnames(train_data)){
  train_label <- train_data[,c(col)]
  test_pred <- knn(train = train_mat[ ,!(colnames(train_mat) == "Sentiment")], test = test_mat[ ,!(colnames(test_mat) == "Sentiment")], cl = as.factor(train_label), k=6)

  table(test_pred,test_data[, col])
  acc.RF = mean(test_pred==test_data[, col])
  acc.RF
  confusionMatrix(table(test_pred,test_data[, col]))
}

Error in knn(train = train_mat[, !(colnames(train_mat) == "Sentiment")],  : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

1. train/test_data = original dataframe
2. train/test_mat = TFIDF features
   the original target variables are present in the train/test_data.

I am getting the following error.

Sentiment is a variable, which is main to predict, but i want to train with all variables present in the train/test original df.

Please, in train/test_mat, I have appended Sentiment column, so I am excluding it while feeding features to KNN.

Comment: your answer is working, but I am facing another error, which is bcoz of different labels in my train and test data. Can you please post it as answer, I will mark it as answer. Thanks

Comment: You should probably transform your class variable to a factor before dividing the dataset into test and training subsets. If class has levels 1:4 in test, but levels 0:6 in train, you confuse knn by making it think you're predicting oranges with apples. If your n is too small, you may need to bootstrap the validation dataset instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `Map`, the wrapper to `mapply` and build a list of confusion matrices passing each column from *test* and *train* data elementwise. Also, consider `transform` in removing *Sentiment*:

```
matrix_process <- function(test_label, train_label) {

  test_pred <- knn(train = transform(train_mat, Sentiment = NULL), 
                   test = transform(test_mat, Sentiment = NULL), 
                   cl = as.factor(train_label), k=6)

  print(table(test_pred, test_label))
  acc.RF = mean(test_pred == test_label)
  print(acc.RF)

  return(confusionMatrix(table(test_pred, test_label)))    
}

conf_matrix_list <- Map(matrix_process, test_data, train_data)

# EQUIVALENTLY:
conf_matrix_list <- mapply(matrix_process, test_data, train_data, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A likely problem is that R expects a vector entry to `cl` but you have a `data.table`. Unlike `data.frame`, selecting a single column in rectangular coordinates with a label of length 1 produces a `data.table` of dim n times 1. Calling `length` on `data.table` gives the number of columns which is 1. `knn`'s internals compares that length to the number of rows in `train` and throws an error. Try subsetting with `train_data[[col]]` instead.